# Reducing vertical space between radio buttons in PyQT

Tags: pyqt5

I'm trying to condense the vertical spacing between a group of radio buttons in PyQT and am struggling. I would like the 3 options in the picture to be vertically closer together...

[image]

Code for reproducing:

```
class MyPopUp(QWidget):
def __init__(self, task=None):
    super(MyPopUp, self).__init__()
    self.task = task

    self.setMinimumSize(400,600)

    self.populate_fields()

def populate_fields(self):

    self.task_popup_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.setLayout(self.task_popup_layout)

    # When do you need to get it done by
    self.scheduling_header_label = QLabel("<h3>Getting it done</h3>")
    self.task_popup_layout.addWidget(self.scheduling_header_label)

    # Deadline date
    self.deadline_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.deadline_date_label = QLabel("When does it need to be complete by?")
    self.deadline_layout.addWidget(self.deadline_date_label)
    self.deadline_dateedit = QDateEdit(calendarPopup=True)
    self.deadline_dateedit.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)
    self.deadline_dateedit.setDateTime(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7))
    self.deadline_layout.addWidget(self.deadline_dateedit)
    self.task_popup_layout.addLayout(self.deadline_layout)

    # Type of deadline
    self.deadline_type_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.task_popup_layout.addLayout(self.deadline_type_layout)
    self.deadline_type_label = QLabel("How strict is the deadline")
    self.deadline_type_label.setWordWrap(True)
    self.deadline_type_layout.addWidget(self.deadline_type_label)

    self.deadline_group_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    
    self.deadline_type_layout.addLayout(self.deadline_group_layout)
   
    self.deadline_group = QButtonGroup()
    self.soft_deadline_radio = QRadioButton("Target Deadline")
    self.deadline_group_layout.addWidget(self.soft_deadline_radio)
    self.deadline_group.addButton(self.soft_deadline_radio)
    self.hard_deadline_radio = QRadioButton("Hard Deadline")
    self.hard_deadline_radio.setChecked(True)
    self.deadline_group_layout.addWidget(self.hard_deadline_radio)
    self.deadline_group.addButton(self.hard_deadline_radio)
    self.specific_deadline_radio = QRadioButton("Must be done on this exact day")
    self.deadline_group_layout.addWidget(self.specific_deadline_radio)
    self.deadline_group.addButton(self.specific_deadline_radio)
```

Comment: You probably set a minimum size or spacing somewhere, but we cannot know it unless you provide a [mre].

Comment: I guess I was asking a more generic question on how to adjust the space specifically for a set of radio buttons. In any case I've added some code to reproduce above and you are correct, I have used a minimum size for this popup window.

Comment: "adjust the space specifically for a set of radio buttons" has no sense in Qt. Besides, while the Qt stylesheet system supports (QSS), it only considers *widgets*, and: 1. widgets are not webpages; 2. layouts are not widgets. Besides, using a minimum size that is bigger than the minimum size hint results in all widgets and *inner layouts* to take all the space they need. `self.deadline_group_layout.setSpacing(0)`. Also see [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and all the basic [class documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html) (including inherited classes).

Comment: Tried self.deadline_group_layout.setSpacing(0) but no joy. I understand the layout managers and why they do what they do in terms of sizing, I just wasn't happy with the way that this came out. Noted RE CSS for widgets only, that's a point I hadn't considered when asking this question. So the short version of the answer is "no, you can't do this without creating your own layout class and butchering the layout sizing logic"?

Comment: No, subclassing QLayout is a very rare case: what I meant is that you should "just" check out the *whole* documentation of all Qt classes that inherit from QLayout. Also, testing and playing around with Qt Designer is always a good source of knowledge. Still, without any MRE, it's impossible to really understand the issue: for what we know, it could just be an issue related to system configuration (DPI, font scaling), or even setting improper minimum sizes to nested containers.